# Programming language named "C Set 2"

Tags: programming-languages

Does anyone know anything about a programming language named "C Set 2" which is referenced in the SEI statistics on function point metrics?

I tried to google something about this programming language but this languages name is a collection of non-googlish keywords.

Comment: Probably hard to find on the internet as it predates WWW. See this though http://www.edm2.com/index.php/IBM_C_Set/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C Set/2 was an IBM C product, for OS/2.  I think it was just the IBM version of C, but it's been a long time.

---

Yup, here are some links:

- http://www.os2site.com/sw/info/os2apars/os2apars.txt
- http://www.os2museum.com/wp/os2-history/os2-2-0/
- http://web.archive.org/web/20100725043713/http://pages.prodigy.net/michaln/history/exhibits/index.html

Heh, I taught C++ to the Labs guys who eventually wrote CSet.

Comment: guess I'm too young to know about it, because it is not in the timeline of languages on wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_programming_languages

Comment: Well, it's really not a *language* per se.  I've been thinking about it, and I'm almost positive that "C Set" was the product name for IBM's C compilers, and "C Set/2" was the OS/2 specific product.  I used it to write device drivers for OS/2, I'm almost positive.

Answer (score 1):

C Set/2 was the C compiler for OS/2. Used it when I worked on OS/2 way back in the day.